# React-redux remove data in store after it was shown once

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have component `AddCarWash` which show form and when this form is submitted I make redirection `browserHistory.push(url)` to another component `AllCarWash`. Additionaly before redirection I put in redux store `message : 'CarWash was save successfully'`. This message will be shown in destination component `AllCarWash`.

Obviousely that this message should be shown only once and in any futher user action it shouldn't be displayed. So I have to remove data from redux store when I was shown. How can I do this? Put `resetMessageHandler` in each and every `Link` in the page or there is much easy way ?

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use componentWillUnmount() to hold a dispatched action, which will fire when the component is navigated away from.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
        // destroy errors for the form here
        this.props.destroyErrorMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what you can do, when you receive message in redux on  componentWillReceiveProps or ComponenetWillMount then you can set a Timeout in method for 20-30sec and in timeout function update the state

```
//sample code
componentWillReceieveProps(props){
 if(props.message){
  setTimeout(()=>{ 
   this.props.dispatch(removeMessageAction())
  },5000);
 }
}
```

same you can write to componentWillMount function, alternatively you can also use componentDidUpdate and componentDidMount method

Comment: It may works but it's a little bit different behaivior then I want

Comment: then i have alternative advice, set a flag when you receive the msg in props and on next render if flag is still set then remove the message, but you should use time too because two renders can happend back to back sometime